# UITextField content into another UItextField

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I have a requirement where I need to copy the content from one UITextField into another UITextField on the same screen. It's like an alias, as soon as the user start typing I should start copying the content. I'm using method `(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string`

The problem is that I have to implement also logic to delete the content. I'm pretty sure that there is a more convenient mechanism.

Any help will be appreciated.

Many thanks,
Marcos.

Comment: I think you on the right track. Just continue to implement your logic and luck will not take a long)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Update your string it's like this :

```
NSString *str = textField.text;
str = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
```

after that assign `str` to your other textfield and it sould be ok.